# Android app crashes on 4.4.4 device but not 4.4.2/5.0 emulator?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm using Android Studio to develop my first app.  On my 4.4.4 device, I can launch MainActivity but when I click something on the screen that navigates to another activity, the app crashes.  It only crashes on my one device, and runs fine on my Note 2 running 4.4.2, as well as two emulators running 4.4.2 and 5.0.

I've tried downloading several free LogCat apps onto my device, but none of them have worked.  Otherwise, I'm unable to view any sort of LogCat message on my computer because I'm unable to download Samsung's device driver (constantly getting timed out).  Both emulators aren't crashing, but they give OpenGL errors.

Here is my MainActivity, if that's not enough then the full code is [here](https://github.com/broskj/JaxComedy/).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SharedPreferences firstCheck,
        spPointValue,
        spNotifications,
        spSpreadsheets;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
final int initialPointValue = 15;
int screenWidth, screenHeight;
static final String prefsPointValueName = "userPointValue",
        prefsNotificationToggle = "notificationToggle",
        prefsSpreadsheets = "spreadsheets",
        directionsURI = "geo:0,0?q=11000+Beach+Blvd+Jacksonville+Fl+32246",
        facebookURL = "https://www.facebook.com/ComedyClubOfJacksonville",
        twitterURL = "https://twitter.com/comedyclubofjax",
        showSpreadsheetURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ax2-gUY33i_pRHZIwR8AULy6-nbnAbM8Qm5-CGISevc/gviz/tq",
        dealsSpreadsheetURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dnpODnbz6ME4RY5vNwrtAc6as3-uj2rK_IgtYszsvsM/gviz/tq";
Intent browserIntent, alarmIntent/*, updateIntent*/;
MyAdapter adapter;
ListView listView;
ConnectivityManager connMgr;
NetworkInfo networkInfo;
ArrayList<Show> shows;
ArrayList<Offer> offers;
DateFormat df;
Date today;
java.util.Calendar calendar, updateCalendar;
AlarmManager alarmManager, updateAlarmManager;
PendingIntent pendingIntent, updatePendingIntent;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    System.out.println("onCreate called");

    declarations();
    addMenuButtonFunctionality();
    setListViewAdapter();
    checkFirstRun();
    checkForPastShows();

}//end onCreate

public void declarations() {
    ActivityManager manager = new ActivityManager(this);
    manager.manageActionBar(getActionBar());
    manager.scaleBackground((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutMain), R.drawable.background);
    manager.scaleImage((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivLogo), R.drawable.comedyclublogo2, 1, .5);

    firstCheck = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    shows = new ArrayList<>();
    offers = new ArrayList<>();

    spSpreadsheets = getSharedPreferences(prefsSpreadsheets, MODE_PRIVATE);

    /*
    creates the ListView adapter and populates the ListView using generateData()
     */
    adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    /*
    simpledateformat used to compare dates from spreadsheet
    to current date
     */
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
    today = new Date();
    today.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

    spNotifications = getSharedPreferences(prefsNotificationToggle, MODE_PRIVATE);

    /*
    alarmmanager and notification declarations
     */
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

    /*
    updateAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    updateIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Update.class);
    updatePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, updateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    updateCalendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    */
}//end declarations

public void manageNotifications() {
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, java.util.Calendar.FRIDAY);
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

        /*
        sets alarm manager to go off at 8:15 in the morning every 7 days on Thursday
        for testing, starts at 815 every morning starting wednesday
         */
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24/*1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7*/, pendingIntent);
}//end manageNotifications

public void updateSpreadsheets() {
    /*
    not currently being used, will revisit later.
     */
    updateCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    updateCalendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    updateCalendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

    updateAlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, updatePendingIntent);
}//end updateSpreadsheets

public void checkForPastShows() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < shows.size(); i++) {
            if (today.after(df.parse(shows.get(i).getShowDate())))
                shows.remove(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < shows.size(); j++) {
                if (shows.get(i).equals(shows.get(j)) && i != j)
                    shows.remove(j);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setListViewAdapter() {
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long arg3) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0://this weekend
                    if (!shows.isEmpty())
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThisWeekend.class).putParcelableArrayListExtra("shows", shows));
                    else {
                        getShows();
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Calendar.class).putParcelableArrayListExtra("shows", shows));
                    }
                    System.out.println("this weekend clicked");
                    break;
                case 1://calendar
                    if (!shows.isEmpty())
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Calendar.class).putParcelableArrayListExtra("shows", shows));
                    else {
                        getShows();
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Calendar.class).putParcelableArrayListExtra("shows", shows));
                    }
                    System.out.println("calendar clicked");
                    break;
                case 2://rewards and offers
                    if (!offers.isEmpty())
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Deals.class).putParcelableArrayListExtra("offers", offers));
                    else {
                        getDeals();
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Deals.class).putParcelableArrayListExtra("offers", offers));
                    }
                    System.out.println("deals clicked");
                    break;
                case 3://food and drink
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FoodAndDrink.class));
                    System.out.println("food and drink clicked");
                    break;
                case 4://groups and parties
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, GroupsAndParties.class).putParcelableArrayListExtra("shows", shows));
                    System.out.println("groups and parties clicked");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}//end setListViewAdapter

public void checkFirstRun() {
    /*
    first run check. If first run, sets reward point value to 15, sets notifications
    to true, manages notifications.
     */
    getShows();
    getDeals();

    if (!firstCheck.getBoolean("firstRun", false)) {
        spPointValue = getSharedPreferences(prefsPointValueName, MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
        editor = spPointValue.edit();
        editor.putInt("pointValue", initialPointValue);
        editor.apply();

        editor = spNotifications.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("notifications", true);
        editor.apply();

        editor = firstCheck.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstRun", true);
        editor.apply();

        manageNotifications();
        //updateSpreadsheets();
    } else {
        try {
            processShowsJson(new JSONObject(spSpreadsheets.getString("showsSpreadsheet", "")));
            processDealsJson(new JSONObject(spSpreadsheets.getString("dealsSpreadsheet", "")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}//end checkFirstRun

private ArrayList<Model> generateData() {
    /*
    populates the ListView on activity_main.xml with an icon and title.
     */
    ArrayList<Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_action_event, "This Weekend"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_action_go_to_today, "Upcoming Shows"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_action_important_gold, "Rewards and Offers"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_action_view_as_list, "Food and Drinks"));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_action_group, "Groups and Parties"));

    return models;
}

public void addMenuButtonFunctionality() {
    /*
    enables overflow menu icon, even with presence of hardware menu key
     */
    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");

        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // presumably, not relevant
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    System.out.println("onOptionsItemSelected called");

    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class));
            System.out.println("settings clicked");
            return true;
        case R.id.action_directions:
            Intent directionsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(directionsURI));
            if (directionsIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(directionsIntent);
            }
            System.out.println("directions clicked");
            return true;
        case R.id.action_about_us:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUs.class));
            System.out.println("about us clicked");
            return true;
        case R.id.action_contact:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Contact.class));
            System.out.println("contact clicked");
            return true;
        case R.id.action_now_hiring:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NowHiring.class));
            System.out.println("now hiring clicked");
            return true;
        case R.id.action_report_a_bug:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReportABug.class));
            System.out.println("report a bug clicked");
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}//end onOptionsItemSelected

public void onFacebookClick(View view) {
/*
handles the click method for the facebook button.  opens an internet intent for the
  comedy club facebook.
 */
    browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(facebookURL));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}//onFacebookClick

public void onTwitterClick(View view) {
/*
handles the click method for the twitter button.  opens an internet intent for the
  comedy club twitter.
 */
    browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(twitterURL));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}//end onTwitterClick

public void getShows() {
    connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    try {
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new DownloadWebpageTask(this, new AsyncResult() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(JSONObject object) {
                    if (!object.toString().equals(spSpreadsheets.getString("showsSpreadsheet", ""))) {
                        System.out.println("shows spreadsheet is the same");
                        processShowsJson(object);
                        editor = spSpreadsheets.edit();
                        editor.putString("showsSpreadsheet", object.toString());
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                }
            }).execute(showSpreadsheetURL);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network not available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("Network info not available.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}//end getShows

public void getDeals() {
    connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    try {
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new DownloadWebpageTask(this, new AsyncResult() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(JSONObject object) {
                    if (!object.toString().equals(spSpreadsheets.getString("dealsSpreadsheet", ""))) {
                        System.out.println("deals spreadsheet is the same");
                        processDealsJson(object);
                        editor = spSpreadsheets.edit();
                        editor.putString("dealsSpreadsheet", object.toString());
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                }
            }).execute(dealsSpreadsheetURL);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network not available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("Network info not available.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void processShowsJson(JSONObject object) {
    try {
        JSONArray rows = object.getJSONArray("rows");

        for (int i = 0; i < rows.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject row = rows.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray columns = row.getJSONArray("c");

            String showDate = columns.getJSONObject(0).getString("v");
            int showTime = columns.getJSONObject(1).getInt("v");
            String comedian = columns.getJSONObject(2).getString("v");
            String description = columns.getJSONObject(3).getString("v");
            String videoURL = columns.getJSONObject(4).getString("v");

            Show show = new Show(comedian, description, showDate, showTime, videoURL);
            shows.add(show);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}//end processShowsJson

private void processDealsJson(JSONObject object) {
    try {
        JSONArray rows = object.getJSONArray("rows");

        for (int i = 0; i < rows.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject row = rows.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray columns = row.getJSONArray("c");

            String offerTitle = columns.getJSONObject(0).getString("v");
            String offerDescription = columns.getJSONObject(1).getString("v");
            int pointValue = columns.getJSONObject(2).getInt("v");

            Offer offer = new Offer(pointValue, offerTitle, offerDescription);
            offers.add(offer);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}//end processDealsJson
```

}

Comment: ` the app crashes`...show us the Logcat

Comment: What David said ... the logcat near certainly tells you what went wrong!

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add that!  There is no LogCat.  It only crashes on the device, and I can't connect it to AS because I'm unable to download Samsung's driver.

Comment: If you install samsung kies, kies will install drivers for you. Or if it's rooted, you can use a remote adb app.

Comment: 1. Try with another computer to get the LogCat
2. Otherwise I would implement ACRA or Crashlytics or another Crash reporting SDK and send the logs automatically to my email - this is very useful while developing anyway (especially if you can test your app when not next to your computer)